# Dark Mist Causes Strange Colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes

I have made mist in my scene,and it works great when it's white mist, but if I try to darken the color, I get all sorts of strange colors appearing in the background of my scene. How do I make the strange colors disappear?

[image: Render Layers > Map Value, Render Layers > Mix, Map Value > Mix > Composite]

My node setup

---

[image: Withough Mist]

My scene without mist

---

[image: White mist]

Light Mist

---

[image: Dark mist with weird colors]

Dark mist makes weird colors appear in the background

Comment: Shot in the dark: try enabling the "clamp" checkbox on the mix node. Does that fix it?

Comment: @JtheNinja Thanks for your tip. It didn't fix it, but it ended up leading me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Mix shader needs to be changed to an Add shader.

[image]

I don't know exactly how these each work, but depending on what color you want your mist to be, different mixing methods work better.